# Limiting dragged view distance

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

i am implementing dragging of a view horizontally. so far everything is working good.

i have one question how can i limit the drag movement or put certain limit from where the view should stop moving even when user is still dragging. same like navigation drawer movement.

Thanks.

tried to implement with onTouchListener

Comment: try out this lib hope i will be help full for you https://github.com/aitsuki/SwipeMenuRecyclerView

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.